# Does any other browser offer Firefox's Tree Style Tab feature?

Tags: windows, web-browser

The Firefox add-on [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) allows hierarchical tab ordering.

Does any other main browser have such a feature or provide an extension for it?

Comment: Not sure if it qualifies as a "main browser", but my Chromium-based [Doogie](https://cretz.github.io/doogie/) browser has tree-style tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Chrome has a similar extension: [**Sidewise Tree Style Tabs**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sidewise-tree-style-tabs/biiammgklaefagjclmnlialkmaemifgo?hl=en). The functionality is similar, but it behaves a bit differently...

Because of the way Chrome handles its GUI, extensions don't have as much freedom to take space inside the browser window. So that means that this extension actually opens in a small separate window.

Comment: Chrome's Sidewise does not have the functionality of Firefox's Tree Style Tabs. I tried using Chrome, but it didn't allow me to have my tabs available at all times. I had to open Sidewise each time I wanted to see them. I went back to Firefox where my tabs are visibly there whenever I want to see them.

Comment: zepe, that's exactly what my second paragraph is talking about. The functionality is similar, but the interface is different.

Comment: It is depressing that this honestly seems to be the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In Opera, there's [something similar](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/tab-stacking-is-here?startidx=50) available, but simpler. It allows stacking tabs, but no tree structures (e.g stacks inside stacks) are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Opera now has [Tree Tabs](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/tree-tabs/) which is quite similar: it is displayed in the sidebar etc.